# Troubleshooting customer email missing in orders

Tags: magento-1.9, email

Customer email is required in one step checkout, however, in the last three months I have had a few orders that have not captured the customers email or at least not saved it to the Magento order.

The only thing I can find in common with the customers are that they are checkout out as guests. I believe the only thing interacting with OSC is our email marketing platform Bronto.

Comment: Are you certain they are guest orders and not customer orders where the customer hasn't been associated with the order correctly? We've encountered this on a store that doesn't have guest checkout enabled, but we get orders that look like guest orders. I've never found the root cause, but it seems to happen when customers attempt multiple payment methods. May be completely unrelated.

Comment: Are you sure you're validating email input both front and backend? Also, are you sure there isn't empty space saved in the email field?

Comment: I'm not sure where to look in magento for email validation on the backend. On the frontend, Magento's built-in javascript is validating the email input.